# .bash_profile not allowing export paths

Tags: redhat, bash

So I'm trying to edit the .bash_profile on a remote [University] server for my personal profile. I have no root access, and the end goal of this project is to be able to run python from my own account. I have python installed in my own directory (in ~/python/Python-2.7.11/), but now in order to be able to use it, I'm trying to simply point the .bash_profile in the right direction with:

```
export PATH = $HOME/python/Python-2.7.11/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.11
```

However, every time I try to run `source .bash_profile` I get

```
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
```

I've been looking around for how to fix this for a few hours, so if this is another repost, I'm sorry, but I still just haven't been able to find anything that works.

Thanks for any help that comes my way!

Comment: export is a bash built-in (on my debian system)

Comment: What shell do you use? What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: DYZ,
'>echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh'

Answer (score 3):

You are using tcsh but setting things via bash commands.  For tsch, use the setenv command - check out https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-set-path-variable-in-c-shell/